# jquery toggle icon using SVG sprite file

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have a script below that toggles a favorites icon.

How do I modify this script to be a link button to use an SVG sprite file and display the desired icon from my sprite file, and if its possible to use inline images alternatively? Would this work??

I will have a number of these link buttons on the same pages as well, so what will I have to change to ensure one doesn't call/conflict with the other, and vice-versa?

FYI: the snippet doesn't run because I dont have an example svg file

I am not sure how to make this work...

thanks people :)

```js
$(function() {
$('verify').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
  $(this).toggleClass('verified');
  $.post('/yourUpdateUrl', {
      'verified': $(this).hasClass('verified'),
      'id': id
    },
    function(data) {
      //some sort of update function here
    });
});
});
});
```

```css
.verify {
  text-indent: -5000px;
  display: block;
  background: transparent url(../images/icon-sprite.svg) [coords for empty icon];
  height: [height of icon];
  width: [width of icon];
}
.verify.verified {
  background-position: [coordinates for svg icon];
}
```

```html
<div id="[item id, probably a number]">
  <p><a href="" class="verify">verify</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not terribly clear what specific problem you have. Have you tried something and hit a blocking point? Is it that you don't know how to set the new coordinates via the JavaScript/jQuery? If each .verify is contained in a div with a unique ID, I don't think there should be a conflict issue. However, note that ID values can't begin with a number.

Comment: @Max Starkenburg thanks for your help. I am not well versed in using SVG icons at all, so that is probably why I am not clear on what I am asking... I see what you mean about using unique ID's, that's fine I guess. I am concerned about compatibility issues...Do you think the icons can be manipulated with my jquery code above together with inline SVG instead of using background images in the CSS?

Comment: I'm not terribly well-versed either, but SVGs aren't going to have as much cross-browser support as something like a PNG, of course, but it depends on what browsers you need to support. You may have already seen this: https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/ which show how they've done SVG sprites and also mentions browser support.

Comment: @Max Starkenberg No worries. I've seen that link too.. there is a method of adding a PNGfallback directly in the CSS as well: `body {
  background: url(fallback.png);
  background: url(background.svg),
    linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
}` like so,  so I may do that :)

Comment: This doesnt seem to work with SVGs. Can anyone else help me out here?